# TypeError: this.state.contracts.map is not a function React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, async-await

I have seen this before but I still am stuck. My code where I fetch the data is as follows:

```
 async componentDidMount(){
   try {
     const res = await 
     fetch('https://templates.accordproject.org/template-library.json');
  const data = await res.json();
  this.setState({
  contracts: data,
  });
 } catch(e) {
 console.log(e);
   }
 }
```

I call it here:

```
 {this.state.contracts.map(contract => <Contract key={contract.id} contract={contract} />)}
```

I can see that state is:

```
 contracts: 

 {
"acceptance-of-delivery@0.0.3": {
    "name": "acceptance-of-delivery",
    "description": "This clause allows the receiver of goods to inspect them for a given time period after delivery.",
    "version": "0.0.3",
    "ciceroVersion": "^0.3.0",
    "type": 1
},   /// etcv for long string of json
```

I get the following error:

```
 TypeError: this.state.contracts.map is not a function
```

I am fairly certain that map expects an array but this isn't one. My question is:

If this is the problem how do I make this.state.contracts an Array so that map will work?

Comment: What do you have in the constructor for defining `this.state`? Most probably you are not setting the value for `contracts` an initial empty array like `[]`.

Comment: You can use console.log in your JSX while debugging {console.log(this.state.contracts)} so you can check what you are trying to map.

Comment: I am setting stat to an empty array:  `state = {
    contracts: [],
  }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

map() is an array method. You can use

```
Object.keys(this.state.contracts).map(key=>({[key]:this.state.contracts[key]}))
```

This will convert the object into an array of each contract.

Or, in the above example you can try:

```
Object.keys(this.state.contracts).map(key=>(<Contract key={this.state.contracts[key].id} contract={this.state.contracts[key]} />))
```

[MDN Object.keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) - Detailed on Mozilla Dev.

Also, Object.values() and Object.entries() may help.